# Uncorrelated variables linearly transformed, ensuring uncorrelation.

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ be real random variables and define $ \begin{pmatrix} \tilde{X}\\ \tilde{Y} \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} a & b\\ c & d \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} X\\ Y \end{pmatrix}$ where $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$.

I need to determine what demands need to be set on $a,b,c,d$ so that $E(\tilde{X}\tilde{Y}) = 0$ (i.e. theyre uncorrelated) given that $E(X)=E(Y)=0$, $V(X)=V(Y)=1$ and $E(XY)=0$. I have already determined that $E(\tilde{X})=E(\tilde{Y})=0$ and that if the matrix is orthogonal $V(\tilde{X})=V(\tilde{Y})=1$.

If I just insert the definitions of the transformed variables I end up with something along the lines of $acE(X^2) + bdE(Y^2)$ which leads me to the condition that $a$ or $c$ and $b$ or $d$ needs to be zero but that seems very harsh to me.

EDIT: I was thinking maybe subtracting $acE(X)^2$ and $bdE(Y)^2$ since theyre both zero and I could use that to get the variance on from the aforementioned result. I know the variance is $1$ so if $ac=-bd$ what does this mean for the matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. Your calculation of $E(\tilde X \tilde Y)=acE(X^2)+bd E(Y^2)$ is correct but can be simplified further, because $E(X^2)=V(X)+[E(X)]^2=1$. So the condition that makes $E(\tilde X\tilde Y)=0$ is $ac+bd=0$.

Comment: Nice, I figured it out just as you wrote this! Does this mean the matrix enjoys any particular property? (I'm asking since the other tasks I'm doing involve alot of orthogonal matrices)

Comment: @Neutronic If you combine $ac+bd=0$ with the requirement that $V(\tilde X)=V(\tilde Y)=1$, you've got only one free parameter left. Try writing $a=\cos\theta$ and $b=\sin\theta$, $c=\cos\phi$, $d=\sin\phi$. I suspect that under all three requirements, the only permissible transformations will be rotations...